# Edit Redux Form with FieldArray

Tags: redux-form

I have create a Redux Form with FieldArray as mentioned in its example, where you can add multiple Member and Hobbies and Submit the Form.

https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/examples/fieldarrays/

Can we Edit the same Form by accessing the form from database? The Edit form should display all the fields and Button I have created before ?

Please advise how different sub-component(which is created using FieldArray ) will populate the values.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse the same form for editing.

A field array is mapped into redux as array of objects or array of strings (depending how you do the `fields.push`).

If you provide that exact format to the `initialValues` prop when you mount the redux form, it will populate the `FieldArray` accordingly

Comment: Can you please provide more details. Do I need to assign the values from database (JSON Data ) to initialValues in componentDidMount method ? Before that, when I read from database, Do I need to store the values in Store ?

Comment: i have the same problem, and i don't understand how to do this. thanks